# How To Increase Callback Frequency of AVAudioEngine.installTap()

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm trying to create an audio visualizer and I'm using the accelerate framework functions to compute the root means square value of the buffer data to get a uniform scalar for my metal shader.

I have an onscreen midi controller where the users can press the buttons to make a sound.

The sounds I'm playing are very short. For example, I have sound buttons that the user presses which makes a beat, this only lasts for about 0.2-0.4s and I only get about 3-4 callbacks during the play.

My visualizer looks quite awful and choppy as it just snaps to 4 different sizes per button press rather than having a smooth transition.

I'm going for a look like this:

[image]

Do I install a second tap? Should I try and interpolate the points to "fake" the transitions?

Ideally, I'd like something along the lines of 10-15 frames/second.

Comment: You can present all circles with different alpha or color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is is no way to increase the frequency, I resorted to interpolating the previous value with the current value to smoothen the transition.

Comment: How did you find out that there are not way to increase frequency? Having the same issue.